# Adding a layer of business intelligence to Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

My team manipulates large quantities of documents (mostly PDFs and .xls files) on Dropbox. We tag the documents, we edit them, we authorize them, etc.
I'm trying to add some business intelligence to this process. Without entering into too much detail, each document has an acquisition cost and an editing cost. Sometimes it's more relevant to calculate ratios based on the size of the file, sometimes you need to look at the number of rows or words, etc.
Is there a way to log this information using an app connected to Dropbox? I love Dropbox but sometimes it feels like a dumb black box.
If Dropbox can't deliver this functionality, I guess we'll have to resort to a document management software. Based on what I described, can you recommend one?
Thank you.